# Can not compare Values of Variable with strings in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, iscsi

I am trying to get info about an iSCSI-Targets Connectionstate.

Ideally I want to have a variable with a value that is True or False for connected or not connected, so that i can run commands to connect or disconnect as needed.

If i set the Variable directly it's working fine. Setting the Variable with the output of a cmdlet seems to work but comparing the Values False or True with IF is always resulting in True. For me the question is: where is the difference between setting the Variable directly to True and using the output of the cmdlet...?

Sample one:

```
$IsConnected=true

if($IsConnected -eq 'true') {
    echo IsConnected!
} else {
    echo IsNotConnected
}
```

Results, as expected, in: `IsConnected`

Sample two:

```
$IsConnected=False
if($IsConnected -eq 'true') {
    echo IsConnected!
} else {
    echo IsNotConnected
}
```

Results, as expected, in: `IsNotConnected`

So now my knowledge ends...:

Sample three:

```
PS ~> $IsConnected=get-iscsitarget | select -ExpandProperty IsConnected
PS ~> echo $IsConnected
True
PS ~> if($IsConnected -eq 'True') {Echo "IsConnected"}else{echo "IsNotConnected"}
IsConnected
PS ~> if($IsConnected -eq 'False') {Echo "IsConnected"}else{echo "IsNotConnected"}
IsConnected
PS ~> if($IsConnected -eq '17beerarenotenaugh') {Echo "IsConnected"}else{echo "IsNotConnected"}
IsConnected
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell's comparison operators are *overloaded*, meaning they might have different behaviors based on the type of *operand* you provide.

The behavior depends entirely on the type of the left-hand side (**lhs**) operand you provide, and PowerShell will try to convert the right-hand side (**rhs**) to the same.

In your example, the value of the `$IsConnected` variable is a `[bool]` - and PowerShell therefore attempts to convert the rhs operand to a `[bool]` to.

The conversion logic for `[string]` to `[bool]` is:

- Empty strings = `$false`
- Non-empty strings = `$true`

Since `'True'`, `'False'` and `'17beerarenotenaugh'` are *all **non-empty***, the `if` conditions are basically interpreted as:

```
if($IsConnected -eq $true) { ... }
if($IsConnected -eq $true) { ... }
if($IsConnected -eq $true) { ... }
```

Use the automatic variables `$true` and `$false` to avoid this:

```
PS ~> if($IsConnected -eq $false) {Echo "IsConnected"}else{echo "IsNotConnected"}
IsNotConnected
```

alternatively, use the `-not` operator:

```
PS ~> if(-not $IsConnected) {Echo "IsConnected"}else{echo "IsNotConnected"}
IsNotConnected
```

Comment: Works! thanks!I've used the $True/$False automatic variables.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for helping!. Our NAS disconnects sometimes or just don't connect after Reboot so maybe some others find this usefull...:

```
$IsConnected = Get-IscsiTarget | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IsConnected
If($IsConnected -eq $false)
{
    Get-IscsiTarget | Where-Object -Property NodeAddress -Like "iqn.2000-01.com.synology:nas01.Target-myiqnnumber" |
    Connect-IscsiTarget -AuthenticationType ONEWAYCHAP -ChapUsername mychapuser -ChapSecret mychapuserssecret
}
else
{
    echo "IsConnected=$Isconnected iSCSI-Drive:OK"
}
```

Comment: Consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) Mathias's answer if it was helpful to you :)